# getBoundingClientRect is not a function on Angular 11 - Three.js

Tags: angular, getboundingclientrect

I try several time to solve this issue but I have not been able to find a solution, I hope that someone could help me.
I'm trying to provide information about the size of the images on my webpage to implement the scroll later, this is my code:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let images = [{...document.querySelectorAll('img')}];
    this.addImages(images);
  }

 addImages(images) {
    this.imageStore = images.map(img => {
      let bounds = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      console.log(bounds);

      let geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(bounds.width, bounds.height, 1, 1);
      let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 })
      let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
      this.scene.add(mesh);

      return {
        img: img,
        mesh: mesh,
        top: bounds.top,
        left: bounds.left,
        width: bounds.width,
        height: bounds.height
      }
    })
  }
```

That code should return the sizes of the images on my HTML page, but I got the error

Comment: ... how this should be actually I recon: `[{...document.querySelectorAll('img')}];` ..?

Comment: @Vovan_Super to get an array of images from my HTML page

Comment: ... well, I mean, `document.querySelectorAll` ruterns a `NodeList` => you (trying to) desctructure it into object inside array => so Array has a single object (with keys: 0, 1, 2 ...)  .. is that what you wanted ( .. cuz when `img.getBoundingClientRect();` is like: " call "getBoundingClientRect()" on {0: Node ... } .. ?

Comment: I mean, why not just: ` ... let images = document.querySelectorAll('img') // iterateble ` ..?

Comment: Yep your right but I querySelector doesn't accept (in this case) getBoundingClientRect(), I don't know why.. So, I also tried to implement: document.getElementById('img').getBoundingClientRect(); And then with forEach: `addImages(images) { console.log(images); images.forEach(img => { img.getBoundingClientRect(); console.log(img); }); ` but always the same

Comment: @Raquel, about your "solution" use setTimeout. It's **not** the solution (What happens if the images spend more time than 200 miliseconds?) use the event `(load)` in each imagen

Comment: Hi @Eiseo, good question thanks.. I gonna try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img'));

    const imgObj = images.map((img) => {
      const bounds = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      return {
        img,
        name: img.name,
        top: bounds.top,
        bottom: bounds.bottom,
        left: bounds.left,
        width: bounds.width,
        height: bounds.height,
      };
    });

    console.log('Applying...');
    console.log({ imgObj });
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yeu1hx?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: many thanks, the creation of an array from querySelectorall solve my issue actually :)

Comment: @Raquel, if you don't wait to images loaded, the width and height will be false unless you force in .html

Comment: @Eliseo, ... `ngAfterViewInit` ...

Comment: @Vovan_Super, nop, try clear cache using CTRL+F5 and check it. ngAfterViewInit not wait to load an image (I updated my answer to get also in the array the htmlElement and to have the array in order)

Comment: @Vovan_Super I added setTimeout with a function inside with the code above
 `ngAfterViewInit() {setTimeout(() => {this.addImages();}, 200);}`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you need **wait** to the images are loaded.

if your images are in an array (some like)

```
  images=["https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1",
          "https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2"]
```

You show it in a *ngFor, use the event `(load)`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let img of images">
<img #mimg [src]="img" (load)="pushData(mimg)">
</ng-container>

  array:any[]=[]
  pushData(el:any)
  {
   this.array.push(el.getBoundingClientRect())
   if (this.array.length==this.images.length)
   {
       console.log("all images loaded")
       ..do something..
   }
  }
```

**Update** as we don't know the order the images are loaded, we can force passing the index

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let img of images;let i=index">
<img #mimg [src]="img" (load)="pushData(mimg,i)">
</ng-container>
  pushData(el:any,index:number)
  {
   this.array[index]={
     ...el.getBoundingClientRect(),
     img:el
   }
   if (!this.array.find(x=>!x))
   {
          console.log("all images loaded")
   }
  }
```